# how to split words in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, word-wrap

Problem: text is shown without line break or chr(10);

suppose test

column_name (text)

```
       hello world hello world hello world hello world.
       hello world.
```

sql i tried

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE( text, CHR(10) ), CHR(13) )  
from dual
```

but it still give output in single line.

```
hello world hello world hello world hello world.hello world.
```

any solution is most welcome.

Solution that worked

```
select REPLACE(REPLACE(textn,chr(10) , '<br>'),chr(13),'') 
  INTO v_text 
from dual;
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked

Sql

```
 select REPLACE(REPLACE(textn,chr(10) , '<br>'),chr(13),'') 
     INTO v_text 
  from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

try in this way

```
select REPLACE(text, string_to_be_replaced, chr(10)||chr(13)) from dual;
```

result for SQL Developer:

[image]

Comment: its still comming in one line.

Comment: i tried with  select REPLACE(text,chr(13) , chr(10)||chr(13)) from dual;

Comment: which developer tool are you using?

Comment: sqldeveloper oracle 12c

Comment: then you need to double click on cell to see formatted text

Comment: yes it working but problem is when i tried to print this content in pdf all content comes without spaces.

Comment: this is something else. I cannot make comment about that. I Suggest you to open new question, and If you believe that this answer helped you please upvote. thank you